Distance to a set and normal cone
We consider a nonempty set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\notin S$. We define the set
$$
P_{S}(x) =\{z\in S : \lVert z - x\rVert =d(x,S)\}
$$
I would like to prove that for all $z\in P_{S}(x)$ we have $x-z\in N_{S}(z)$ where
$$
N_{S}(z) = \{y\in\mathbb{R}^n : \langle w,y\rangle\leq 0, \forall w\in T_{S}(z)\}
$$
and where $T_{S}(z)$ is composed of elements $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exist sequences $(x_n)_n\subset S$ and $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ a sequence of positive real numbers such that $x_n$ converges to $z$ and $\varepsilon_n$ converges to $0$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n - z}{\varepsilon_n} = w
$$
Clearly if $P_{S}(x)$ is empty it is vacuously true. However, if $P_{S}(x)\neq\emptyset$ I don't know how to proceed. If the set $S$ is convex it is just a consequence of the fact that $\langle x-z,y-z \rangle\leq 0$ for all $y\in S$ if $\lVert z - x\rVert =d(x,S)$.
Do you have some ideas on how to tackle the proof please ?
Thank you a lot !

This all follows from the definitions:
Take $z\in P_S(x)$, $w\in T_S(z)$, $\frac1{\epsilon_n}(x_n-z) \to w$. Then
$$
0 \le  \|x_n-x\|^2 - \|z-x\|^2 = 2\langle z-x, x_n-z\rangle + \|x_n-z\|^2.
$$
Divide by $\frac1{\epsilon_n}$, pass to the limit gives
$$
0 \le 2\langle z-x, w\rangle + 0,
$$
which proves the claim.

Thank you for the answer, however when you divide by $\varepsilon_n$ to pass to the limit, why $\lVert x_n -z\rVert^2$ goes to $0$ ?

because $\frac1{\epsilon_n}(x_n -z)$ is bounded, so that $\frac1{\epsilon_n}{|x_n-z|^2}=\epsilon_n \cdot \frac1{\epsilon_n^2}{|x_n-z|^2}\to 0$.

I was too lazy, thank you a lot.
